# YUI Compressor security?

Tags: javascript, css, security, yui-compressor

Is [YUI Compressor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yuicompressor) secure to use with a code editor to minify CSS and JS files?

Looking at the above NPM package page it hasn't been updated since 2013 as I believe Yahoo stopped supporting the YUI library.

Comment: Secure against what?

Comment: It minifies code. Are you expecting it to inject something unsavory in the result?

Comment: By secure I meant actually running it and having it on my local machine.